# how to know which specific exception to catch

Tags: c#, .net, exception

For example

```
try
{
    Application.Exit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    //throw;
}
```

this is generic exception. How to know which one to use and when ?

Comment: You can not know that for sure, unless *you* are not raising them, for some reason.

Comment: Never, *never* catch an exception like that.  Application.Exit() failing is a condition you can never properly handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to know wich one to use and when ?

That depends on what you are trying to do in your `try` block. Suppose you are using `SqlCommand` to retrieve some records, then its better to catch `SqlException` first and then `Exception` to catch others.

```
try
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(....))
    {
        //........
    }
}
catch (SqlException se)
{
    //logging etc. 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //logging etc
}
```

Just remember to catch specific exceptions first and the move to base `Exception`. As far as your question about which exception to catch, You can't be sure about them, *that is why they are called exceptions*, you can only predict and catch accordingly.

Comment: @Downvoter, would be glad if you can improve the post

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you might improve it by mentioning that most people accomplish the magic feat of determining what exception(s) to catch by reading the documentation for the method(s) that they're calling. I'm not convinced that anyone actually answered this dude's question, but mainly that's because I'm not sure he phrased it well.

Comment: That is to say, I believe his problem is that he does not know SqlException exists, nor whether his method call could result in it being thrown, nor how to learn that SqlException even exists as a valid exception to catch, not that he doesn't understand how to structure catch blocks. I could be wrong here, but that's how I read the original question. It may also be a combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

You can define many catch blocks. Like:

```
        try
        {
            var result = 8 / 0;
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
        {
            // Here, a more specific exception is caught.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // Otherwise, you'll get the exception here.
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to Use Structured exception handling (SEH) in your programm.

First of all you must to note, that exist 3 types of error:

- programm errors
- user errors
- exception

so you must to use SEH in C# just in situation when exception can be created, but you can do nothing шер you code, during running of programm. During creation of your method you must to put exception  if you method for avoid situation when method cant do requested task. And during this process you must to note 2 main points (as **Rihter** write in one of his book):

First of all you must to understand what type of Exception can be created. This type must be choosen very carefully, for this purpose you can use one of existing types in FCL (Framework Class Library), but sometimes can be such situation, when you requier youe own type of exception. For example if you work with Input-Otput classes you can use one of the following Exception Types - `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException, System.IO.DriveNotFoundException, System.IO.EndOfStreamException, System.IO.FileLoadException, System.IO.FileNotFoundException, System.IO.PathTooLongException, System.IO.PipeException`.

Secondly, you must to choose what message will be sended to exception constructor. Means you must be able to find detailed information from your method - when and why this exception was created.

Also for creating exception you can use next shablon

```
void SomeMEthod (){
try 
{
    //your code to do
}
catch (ExceptionType1) //here put code with Exception 1
{
// you can add some specific code here for working with your exception
}
catch (ExceptionType2) //here put code with Exception 2
{
// you can add some specific code here for working with your exception
}
catch (EXCEPTION) //here put code with rest types of Exception
{
// you can add some specific code here for working with your exception
}
finally
{
//here put code that allow you to free your resourses
//NOTE: this code will be launched always!
}
//here you can placed code, that will be launched if no Exception will be found
}
```

Also please note that `EXCEPTION` must include `ExceptionType2` and `ExceptionType1`, and `ExceptionType2` must include `ExceptionType1` - this allow you to catch exception using some hierarhy - otherwise - `EXCEPTION` will catch all your exception.

Also you can add keywords `thow` in your `catch` block - for double work with existing Exception

```
catch (EXCEPTION) //here put code with rest types of Exception
{
// you can add some specific code here for working with your exception
throw;
}
```

Also you must to understand that if you use code for catching Exception - you know that it can be. So you can make something to take it away. You must to create your code in such way, that q-ty of blocks with `try-catch-funally` was exactly tha your programm required.

Detailed information about Exception classes in C# you can find [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx).